# Type and namespace naming when the type and namespace are the same

Tags: .net, namespaces, naming-conventions

The [.NET design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces) recommends avoiding using the same name for namespaces and a type.

> DO NOT use the same name for a namespace and a type in that namespace.
>
> For example, do not use `Debug` as a namespace name and then also
> provide a class named `Debug` in the same namespace. Several compilers
> require such types to be fully qualified.

Given the above, it would be recommended to not have a `Customer` type defined within a `Company.Entities.Customer` namespace. In which case, there are two possible options I can see:

1. Pluralize the namespace to `Company.Entities.Customers` and have a singular `Customer` type within
2. Retain the singular namespace `Company.Entities.Customer` and leave `Customer` in the `Company.Entities` namespace

Both options seem reasonable and the logical grouping of all related types provided with option 1 feels sensible vs having a single type outside of the namespace (likely repeatedly for types with similar naming issues).

Given the two options, is there a standard approach for this situation or is it opinion based (and therefore this question going to be closed)?

Comment: Why have a `Customer` namespace at all? Are there going to be types within the `Customer` namespace that have the same name as types in other similar namespaces?  In other words, could everything entity-related just be in the `Company.Entities` namespace?

Comment: @DStanley There are other types related to `Customer` and yes there are types within `Customer` that share names with other types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches can be used (personally I would go with second one if selecting from the two), but there are other possibilities worth considering:

1. Add `Entities` suffix to the namespace name i.e. `Company.Entities.CustomerEntities`.
2. Switch from the "group by type" approach (i.e. root level folders for entities/repos/controllers/views etc.) to [Vertical Slice Architecture](https://jimmybogard.com/vertical-slice-architecture/) ([video presentation](https://youtu.be/SUiWfhAhgQw))/Feature Folders approach which personally I've grown fond of over the last years (see [this](https://github.com/OdeToCode/AddFeatureFolders), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/september/asp-net-core-feature-slices-for-asp-net-core-mvc) and [this](https://ardalis.com/api-feature-folders/)).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I like the vertical slice approach, it is a pattern I adopt when starting new projects. This is for an existing project where migrating the architecture is unfortunately not currently an option.

Comment: @RubenHart then I would go with the first option I've suggested (adding suffix to the namespace).

Comment: Thanks. I think I’m going to stick with the horrible current convention (they effectively use the filenames to logically namespace) and then address this properly at a later date.